# Appenders list empty in Logger for Log4net

Tags: log4net

I have the following config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} 
    [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs\Log.txt" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} 
    [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
    <encoding value="utf-8" />
  </appender>

  <logger name="TraceLogger" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
  </logger>
</log4net>
```

I have run Configure on the XmlConfigurator:

```
static class ProgramEntry
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        ...
```

My web.config has:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" requirePermission="false" />    
  </configSections>

...

<log4net configSource="Config\log4net.config" />

...




<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="0">
      <listeners>
        <add name="Log4NetTraceListener" type="BLAH.Log4netTraceListener, BLAH" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

I have a Trace listener implementation:

```
public class Log4netTraceListener : System.Diagnostics.TraceListener
{
    private readonly ILog log;

    public Log4netTraceListener()
    {
        log = LogManager.GetLogger("TraceLogger");

        // disable logging to trace write if logging fails, or else we'll end up in a deadlock.
        log4net.Util.LogLog.EmitInternalMessages = false;
    }

    private string level = "Info";

    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        if (message.Contains("Error:"))
        {
            level = "Error";
        }
        else if (message.Contains("Warning:"))
        {
            level = "Warning";
        }
        else if (message.Contains("Information:"))
        {
            level = "Info";
        }
        else
        {
            if (log != null)
            {
                LogMessage(message);
            }
        }
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        if (log != null)
        {
            LogMessage(message);
        }

        // reset the level
        level = "Info";
    }

    private void LogMessage(string message)
    {
        if (level == "Info")
        {
            log.Info(message);
        }

        if (level == "Error")
        {
            log.Error(message);
        }

        if (level == "Warning")
        {
            log.Warn(message);
        }
    }
}
```

The Trace listener gets run, the "TraceLogger" seems to get found, but its appenders collection is empty.

[image]

What might i be doing wrong? The real issue is that

**EDIT**

Found an error:

> log4net:ERROR Failed to parse config file. Is the 
>   specified as: 
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unable to open
>   configSource file 'Config\log4net.config'.
>   (C:\Users\awdawd\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\BLAH\BLAH\BLAH\bin\Debug\DataFactoryPreparationManager.exe.Config
>   line 36)

My app.config is in the root directory, my Config folder is underneath this directory

Comment: The `configSource` file path is relative to the location of the config file itself. It can also only reference files/folders within its own directory.

Comment: My app.config is inside the root directory of my project. Am i missing something? my Config folder is underneath this directory

Comment: Where is it at runtime? Does your application actually run from a `bin\Debug` folder? (the error message suggests it does) Is the log4net config file copied to `bin\Debug\Config`?

Comment: Holy crap, my file in my solution is log4net.config but whenever i save it, it makes it capital Log4Net.config. What on earth

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `log4net.config` is copied to `bin\Debug\Config` via the 'Copy to Output Directory' property of the file from within Visual Studio.
Right click on the file in the Solution Explorer and select 'Properties'.

Comment: I've done that, i'm now getting a System.StackOverflowException when it called GetLogger("TraceLogger")

Comment: Arghh, i found it. the log.txt file is actually being stored in bin/Debug/Logs folder. Not where i thought it'd be. Apparently the lack of appenders means nothing :)

Comment: It made me look in that folder then i found that the logs were actaully being written out. I did not need to Copy to Output directory.